Calling a stored procedure in DbVisualizer returns message : Invalid operation: result set is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null
I'm running DB2 LUW v11.5.9 on SLES 12.5 (zLinux).
A new stored procedure BRL.LOONCIRCUIT_BTB_V2 has been created which is basically a copy of an existing SP BRL.LOONCIRCUIT_BTB, but with a change in one of the dynamic SQL statements.
When I execute the new SP in tool DbVisualizer  ( version 24.1.5 - pro edition running on Windows 10 enterprise) , I get following return code :
[Code: -4470, SQL State: ]  [jcc][t4][10120][10898][4.33.31] Invalid operation: result set is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null
Executing the old , existing stored procedure works fine.
Executing both stored procedures in another tool (Toad for DB2) works fine as well.
I can provide DDL of the new SP if needed

please edit your question (do not use comments, they are not searchable), and add (1) the exact version of the Dbvisualizer and (2) the operating-system you are using to run DbVisualizer, and (3) whether you tried a different jdbc based tool, e.g squirrelSQL, or Dbeaver.  (toad for db2 may use odbc, not jdbc, i.e. different drivers no common code).

The DbVisualizer version is 24.1.5 - pro edition running on Windows 10  enterprise. I also suspect it is driver related in combination with specific SQL syntax : still investigating

Different drivers have different default settings and different configs. Check also the impact of adding an extra attribute to the jdbc connection-string resultSetHoldability=1;

status update : problem  SQL syntax found in new stored procedure. Opened a case with IBM
